# How to position popover in swift dead center (it's a little off center)

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller, popover

The following code displays an arrowless popover. I tried positioning it dead center in the view but it's a little off. I don't know what to do - I'm a total beginner.

```
@IBAction func PostPop(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showPostPop", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:   AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showPostPop" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController
        let controller = vc.popoverPresentationController

        if let _controller = controller {
            //set anchor and remove arrow
            _controller.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds), 0, 0)
            _controller.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue:0)

        }

        if controller != nil
        {
            controller?.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried subtracting half of your popover width and half of your popover height from the anchor point? CGRectMake takes the coordinates of the top left corner of the view, so it seems as though you aren't taking the width and height into account.

Comment: Oh yea you're right that seems to be the problem. Although subtracting half of the popover dimensions from my anchor rect moves it leftwards and upwards too much. I've kinda resorted to trial and error values for x and y but I'm worried about how it scales in other apple products. This popover is a view controller with 100 height and 100 width set on the storyboard. How does the anchor work? It doesn't start drawing it out in the top left corner it seems.